# Auto fixed the remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a code

check this : https://jsfiddle.net/8ufj9auo/

```
<style>

    .Parent {
        overflow-y:hidden;
        position:fixed;
        left:100px;
        width:25%;
        top:100px;
        bottom:100px;
     }
    .Child_2 {
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:100%;
     }

</style>

<div class="Parent">

<!-- .Child_1 Have variable height -->
    <div class="Child_1"></div>
<!-- .Child_2 must be fixed the remaining height -->
    <div class="Child_2"></div>

</div>
```

but when height  `child_2 = 100%`  , the amount of the height of the `.Child_1` , `.Child_2` knocks out of the box

So what would you suggest me to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the `flex` display. Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ufj9auo/2/) if solves your issue.

Just add these css rules to your `aside`:

```
 aside{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

and this rule to your `.Child_2`:

```
flex: 1;
```

You have to add height to your `.parent` div and then you can use `height: 100%` on your `.Child_2`.

Note:

I noticed you had both `top` and `bottom` properties set to your parrent. I don't know why would want that. You should use `top` and `left` to position it fixed on your page.

You can learn about flex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: you didn't response. What happened?